# TWILIO/PHP - Get recordings between 2 dates with the parent call information

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

My English is not very good, but I'll try to explain the problem as well as possible.

I have to get all the recordings between 2 dates, the problem is that Twilio saves 2 calls, the parent and the child, and when I get the callSid  but the child does not contain the phone numbers of the calls, it contains the TwinML App Sid that I use to make the calls, so I have to call the parent call information of each child's call to get the From and To phone numbers.

I have something like this:

```
$recordings = $client->recordings
                    ->read([
                               "dateCreatedBefore" => new \DateTime('2021-09-10T00:00:00Z'),
                               "dateCreatedAfter" => new \DateTime('2021-09-09T00:00:00Z')
                           ], 200);

foreach ($recordings as $record) {
   $calltest = $client->calls->read(array("parentCallSid" => $record->callSid), 1);
   foreach ($calltest as $callTestData) {
       print($callTestData->from."-".$callTestData->to);
   }
}
```

The problem is that this way of calling the information makes it load very slow. Is there a more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could try to [list all the calls that occurred between those dates first](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-read-multiple-call-resources&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x). Then, when you get a `parentCallSid` that you need to look up to find the child calls, you could do so from the existing data. You might have to do a bunch of call lookups at the start, but once you have cached that data locally, it should be much quicker to look up the rest of the data.